# Using a neural network for regression (with Theano)

Tags: python-2.7, theano

I'm new to theano, and I'm having troubles.
I'm trying to use theano to create a neural network that can be used for a regression task (instead of a classification task)
After reading a lot of Tutorials, I came to the conclusion that I could do that by creating an output layer which just handles the regression, and prepand a "normal" neural net with a few hidden layers. (But that still lies in the future).

So this is my "model":

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python
  2
  3 import numpy as np
  4 import theano
  5 import theano.tensor as T
  6
  7 class RegressionLayer(object):
  8     """Class that represents the linear regression, will be the outputlayer
  9     of the Network"""
 10     def  __init__(self, input, n_in, learning_rate):
 11         self.n_in = n_in
 12         self.learning_rate = learning_rate
 13         self.input = input
 14
 15         self.weights = theano.shared(
 16             value = np.zeros((n_in, 1), dtype = theano.config.floatX),
 17             name = 'weights',
 18             borrow = True
 19         )
 20
 21         self.bias = theano.shared(
 22             value = 0.0,
 23             name = 'bias'
 24         )
 25
 26         self.regression = T.dot(input, self.weights) + self.bias
 27         self.params = [self.weights, self.bias]
 28
 29     def cost_function(self, y):
 30         return (y - self.regression) ** 2
 31
```

to train the model as in the theano tutorials I tried the following:

```
In [5]: x = T.dmatrix('x')

In [6]: reg = r.RegressionLayer(x, 3, 0)

In [8]: y = theano.shared(value = 0.0, name = "y")

In [9]: cost = reg.cost_function(y)

In [10]: T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=reg.weights)


─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────---------------------------------------------------------------------------         [77/1395]
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-0326df05c03f> in <module>()
----> 1 T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=reg.weights)

/home/name/PythonENVs/Theano/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gradient.pyc in grad(c
ost, wrt, consider_constant, disconnected_inputs, add_names, known_grads, return_disconnected
)
    430
    431     if cost is not None and cost.ndim != 0:
--> 432         raise TypeError("cost must be a scalar.")
    433
    434     if isinstance(wrt, set):

TypeError: cost must be a scalar.
```

I feel like I did exactly the same (only with the math I need) like it was done in theanos logistic regression tutorial (http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html) but it doesn't work. So why cant I create the gradients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cost function should probably be a sum of squares. At the moment it is a vector of squares, but you need to condense it down to one value in order to be able to the the gradient of the then scalar function. This is usually done like this:

```
def cost_function(self, y):
    return ((y - self.regression) ** 2).mean()
```

Comment: Why would 26         self.regression = T.dot(input, self.weights) + self.bias return a vector? I mean dot-product returns a scalar, and bias is a scalar too.

Comment: Aah, well usually you put a batch of data in, so `input` would be a matrix.